# Orchard CMS, how to prevent users from editing the same page simultaneously?

Tags: orchardcms

When opening two browsers and editing the same page as different users, the last user who saves overwrites the other user's work without warning.

I have tried looking into workflows but there isn't a signal for when a user starts editing a page.

Is there a way to prevent the scenario described above without customising orchard?

Answer (score 2):

When I was using Orchard heavily back in 2013, we added the [SoNerdy.ConcurrentContent](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/Packages/Orchard.Module.SoNerdy.ConcurrentContent) Orchard module to add this functionality. It worked well for us at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Orchard has no inbuilt way to do this I'm afraid.

It is a little more complicated that it may appear I think. To implement this functionality you'd probably need to add SignalR (or some ajax polling) to monitor when a user has the editor page open. A slightly easier solution to your problem could be to create a part that checks whether the posted modified date has changed since the edit page was opened and lets the user know someone else has edited the page. They can then refresh the editor and redo their edits, not as pretty but simpler to implement.

Comment: Based on the part idea a part could store some sort of lock when someone edits the page and releases it when edit is finished. This way one could display "page is being edited" in the content list.

Comment: Unless they just navigate away without pressing save, then the page is stuck being edited